# How I can help struct infer View type values in a closure that feeds the needed type in SwiftUI?

Tags: swift, swiftui

The code below works:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("Hello, world!")
            .customViewModifier(modifier: { view in CustomModifier(content: { view } )} )
    }
}


struct CustomModifier<Content: View>: View {
    
    let content: () -> Content
    
    var body: some View {
        content()
            .foregroundColor(.red)
    }
}


extension View {
    func customViewModifier<ContentModifier: View>(modifier: (Self) -> ContentModifier) -> some View {
        return modifier(self)
    }
}
```

**My goal** is to be able the code below. Currently, Xcode does not help me to fix the error.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("Hello, world!")
            .customViewModifier(modifier: CustomModifier)
    }
}
```

Is there a way around to make my goal possible?

here was my try to solve the issue:

```
extension View {
    func customViewModifier2<ContentModifier: View>(modifier: (Self) -> ((Self) -> ContentModifier)) -> some View {
        return modifier(self)
    }
}
```

Error:

> Type '(Self) -> ContentModifier' cannot conform to 'View'

Comment: Why don't you just turn it into a `ViewModifier`?

Comment: Maybe you can read question again for finding the word of custom in question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The final real goal is not clear ('cause it is really better to use `ViewModifier` based approach), but if you want to use a type as argument it can be like the following

*compiled with Xcode 13.2 / iOS 15.2

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("Hello, world!")
            .customViewModifier(modifier: CustomModifier.self) // << type !!
    }
}

extension View {
    func customViewModifier(modifier: CustomModifier<Self>.Type) -> some View {
        return modifier.init(content: { self })
    }
}
```